# Possibility for ancient East Asian migration to Australia

Tags: alternate-history

I am developing a country spanning a more fertile Australia, New Guinea and a far larger New Zealand in which its founder and inhabitants are descended from an ancient East Asian, ethnic group similar to the Yayoi and akin groups.

The reason such groups would have ended up here is coming from an ancient belief that a very fertile, not too hot new homeland is waiting for them once they go deep in the south.

What would be the most plausible migration routes?

Comment: Keep in mind that Yayoi people didn't start their migration before 300 BC and likely did not even exist until 1000 BC. By 1000 BC, all "nearby" islands and Australia were already colonized. We need Yayoi to push out virtually any other group in the Pacific (similarly to how they pushed Jōmon people in Japan) for this to work.

Comment: @Alexander I did not say they were Yayoi, I was pointing out they were related but not necessarily the same. Would it work if these people push out the native Australians in the Outback?

Comment: First, if you want Yayoi or similar group to succeed they need to push out Austronesian peoples from all those islands in between. That will take centuries and tens, if not hundreds of thousands of migrants.

Comment: For future reference, please remember that a specific reason to close questions is that they ask more than one question.

Comment: The original inhabitants of New Zealand are for real the descendants of an *"[ancient East Asian ethnic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_languages)"*. As far as historical linguistics can offer a clue, their distant ancestors originated on the island of Taiwan.

Comment: @AlexP The DNA strongly points to Taiwan or nearby. The linguistics are slightly messier; Heyerdahl and co had a point about kumara.

Comment: @SeanOConnor: Linguistics is not messier at all. The *language* of the Maori comes from Taiwan for sure. But linguistics can only tell us about *languages*. Languages are not inherited biologically. Sometimes, the ancestry of the language points to the ancestry of the people, but often it doesn't. For example, most Americans are not descended from Englishmen, most Romanians and Frenchmen are not descended from Italic peoples, and the ancestors of most Egyptians did not come from the Arabian peninsula.

Comment: @AlexP It's nonsense to specify the origin of  language with such precision when they're so different without a clear history. East Asian? Sure. Taiwanese? That's reading DNA results back into linguistic studies. I speak a tiny smattering of Maori; there are parts that sound for all the world like Japanese (e.g. Haere mai); other parts sound like other Asian languages; other, smaller parts are from South America (e.g. kumara), still others seem to be unique. No one knows the exact details of the initial stages of the Polynesians leaving the Asian mainland; linguistic analyses need error bars.

Comment: @SeanOConnor: Maori is Polynesian language, closely related to Tahitian and just a little bit less closely related to Hawaiian. Polynesian languages belong to the [Austronesian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_languages) family. Austronesian languages have *by far* the greatest diversity in Taiwan. (Whatever Maori sounds today is irrelevant. What counts is how the [Proto-Polynesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Polynesian_language) language sounded.) (DNA is completely ignored by historical linguistics. If it matches, fine; if it doesn't, not a linguistics problem.)

Comment: @AlexP Oh, I didn't realise you were a fluent proto-Polynesian speaker. Well, no need for any caution or 'error bars' on your conclusions. Here was me thinking that the very article you cite acknowledges that even the existence of the language is hypothetical...but you know it's (sole) origin down to the neighbourhood! DNA *should* be ignored by limguists, but confirmation bias is one hell of a drug.

Answer (score 3):

**Model your colonizaton event on the Austronesian colonization of the Pacific.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_peoples

> Based on the current scientific consensus, they originated from a
> prehistoric seaborne migration, known as the Austronesian expansion,
> from pre-Han Taiwan, at around 3000 to 1500 BCE. Austronesians reached
> the northernmost Philippines, specifically the Batanes Islands, by
> around 2200 BCE. Austronesians developed sails some time before 2000
> BCE.[49]: 144  In conjunction with their other maritime technologies
> (notably catamarans, outrigger boats, lashed-lug boat building, and
> the crab claw sail), this enabled their dispersal into the islands of
> the Indo-Pacific.

[image: dispersal]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynesians#/media/File:Chronological_dispersal_of_Austronesian_people_across_the_Pacific.svg

Some of the lands they reached were uninhabited.  Some were already inhabited by humans from earlier migrations.

> From 2000 BCE they assimilated (or were assimilated by) the earlier
> Paleolithic Negrito, and Australo-Melanesian Papuan populations. They
> reached as far as Easter Island to the east, Madagascar to the
> west,[50] and New Zealand to the south. At the furthest extent, they
> might have also reached the Americas

The Austronesians might also have encountered Homo florensis or other archaic human types.

It would be no great stretch to model your fiction on the reaL Austronesian migration.  Have them have the characteristics you want.  Or have your people just do the Polynesia part of the migration if you want it later.

Somehow the Austronesians did not take over mainland Australia which I dont understand but is apparently how it was.  If you expand Australia into your desired fictional land you could have your people skip past the inhabited Pacific islands farther North and go to an Australia equivalent.  There will be Australian natives there and that interaction can be part of the fiction.  The real Austronesian migration encountered peoples analogous to the Australian natives and interbred with them, or killed them, or were driven away by them, or coexisted with them - all the usual human stuff.